# simple htaccess question

Tags: .htaccess

Well this is really simple but I have no clue..

I have a htaccess file in home directory which points all php files to index.php on home directory.

```
RewriteRule ^.*php index.php [L]
```

Now i have created a subdirectories like example.com/mydir/

I want a generic htaccess inside subdirectories that should point

example.com/mydir/ to example.com/index.php

and dont consider any other files.

possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all this from the .htaccess in your home directory. See [`mod_rewrite, a beginner’s guide (with examples)`](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) and [`mod_rewriting an entire site`](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/blog/software/open_source/apache/mod_rewriting_an_entire_site).

Comment: thanks, well i wanted to keep things simple, btw which one has more priority, htaccess in home dir or in sub dir ?

Comment: no definately not, also have a look at these:
http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

Try it with an absolute URL path in your substitution:

```
RewriteRule ^.+\.php$ /index.php [L]
```